# android : ProGuard error , there were 4 duplicate class definitions

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-proguard

I am using ksoap2 version 2.4 to connect a .net webservice and get data.I am using ProGuard when I export my application.
I got this error when exporting by proguard.there is no problem when I dont use it.

```
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Note: there were 4 duplicate class definitions.
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser extends or implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.content.Intent depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.content.res.ColorStateList depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] Warning: there were 16 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2016-04-13 11:41:39 - Agency]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

I serached google and found some solutions.but none of them worked.
By using `-dontwarn` my application closed.By using `-keep class` I got the same error.
I am using eclipse.
What i have to do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109308/ksoap2-with-proguard.

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows, you have multiple classes.

I think you have multiple jar files of same library, probably different versions of same library.

So double check your libraries and remove any duplicate if there is any and then `Clean>Restart>Rebuild` the `APK`.