# Error in transform Classes And Resources With Proguard

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

I am recently facing a crash caused by transform Classes And Resources With Proguard after upgrading gradle and android dependencies. I tried all solutions in stack overflow (No successful result).

[image]

> If some one can help to find a solution without downgrading gradle or
>   expose my code to the public by keeping classes in proguard-rules.

**Here is Gradle File App** :

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "####"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 30
        versionName "1.7.35"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: "###",
                onesignal_google_project_number: "###"
        ]
    }

    ext.enableCrashlytics = true

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-RulesActivity.pro'

        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-RulesActivity.pro'

        }
    }

    buildscript {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.3.1'
            }
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.jcodecraeer:xrecyclerview:1.3.2'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
    implementation 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.4'




    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'

    //Firebase

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'

    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.2'

    //RxJava & RxAndroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'

    //Json
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    //Logger
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.0'

    //Material SearchBar
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.6'

    //SQL Encryption
    implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9@aar'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Top-level build file :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        //classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://clojars.org/repo/"
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Here is proguard-rules.pro :**
Note: I tried -ignorewarnings still getting the crash.

```
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.*.* { *; }

-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**


-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-keep public class * implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation
```

**Error Logcat** :

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:207)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:485)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:271)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:113)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:64)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:262)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:65)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:176)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:282)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: UP.............

Comment: If you use git, what code change led to this exception? Can you show a build log?

Answer (score 3):

I also caught this exception when tried to build APK in release with `minifyEnabled true`. Check warnings in `Build` panel by pressing button `Toggle view`.

In my case a problem was in duplicated definitions of libraries `org.xmlpull.v1`, see https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#duplicateclass:

> You should also not add libraries to your application that are already
>   part of the Android runtime (notably org.w3c.dom, org.xml.sax,
>   org.xmlpull.v1, org.apache.commons.logging.Log, org.apache.http, and
>   org.json). They are possibly inconsistent, and the runtime libraries
>   would get precedence anyway.

A problem was in an old library KSoap which provided this Java library. Solutions are written in [Ksoap2 with proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109308/ksoap2-with-proguard). I downloaded the library, removed the duplicated package and added the library in `build.gradle`. Also you can add to `proguard-rules.pro` a line `-ignorewarnings`, but I don't recommend to do it.

UPDATE

I also found the lines in Build log:

```
Warning: okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
```

In https://github.com/square/okio/issues/60 you can see this fixing line:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
```

[image]

Comment: "Check warnings in Build panel by pressing button Toggle view" - Toggle view - is the Key Phrase! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

Add above line to your proguard rules. This tricks work for me.